яндекс карты апи 2.1 - как выделить границы найденного объекта res.geoObjects.get(0)
собственно, реализована отдельный инпут с подсказками и перемещением карты к найденному. хочется чтобы найденное заливалось и очерчивались границы объекта, как на самих яндекс картах. бьюсь не могу найти решение.
при этом если кодировать регионы то там выделение работает, вот так
ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.regions.load("RU", {
       lang: "ru"
     })).search('properties.hintContent = "Мордовия"').setOptions({
       fillOpacity: '0.4',
       fillColor: '#1ab7d8',
       strokeColor: '#fa4d09'
     });

тоже самое но например с москвой - не работает
ymaps.geoQuery(ymaps.geocode('Москва')).setOptions({fillOpacity: '0.4',fillColor: '#1ab7d8',strokeColor: '#fa4d09'});

почему? как реализовать такое?
